# Navigation.PopAsync() não funciona ao ser usado como opção de sair do aplicativo

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Tenho um aplicativo de uma tela somente, uma "ContentPage".

Não consigo sair do app com o "PopAsync()".

Estou debugando em um device Samsung J6.

```
// página instanciada
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Inicio());

// opção usada para sair do aplicativo
private async void Sair(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

Comment: se não há nenhuma outra página na pilha de navegação, parece não fazer sentido um pop... para fechar a aplicação: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30571114/4713574

Comment: Meu Visual Studio não reconhece o objeto/método "OS":
"Android.OS."

Comment: Ou está faltando importar um namespace using Android.OS;, [Usando Namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces), ou está faltando referênciar um Assembly, [como referenciar um Asssembly](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019),

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Utilizo o código abaixo para sair e fechar um App.

```
// opção usada para sair do aplicativo
private async void Sair(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá @Domingos Neto,

Como já foi dito, `Navigation.PopAsync()` é um método para desempilhar janelas em sua aplicação, uma vez que exista somente uma janela tal método não terá utilidade.

Com relação a sua abordagem de "fechar o app programaticamente", o que posso dizer é que esta não é uma abordagem recomendada pelas lojas principalmente pela Apple(mais detalhes através do [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1561/_index.html)), pois tal comportamento pode ser visto pelo usuário como um crash (falha inesperada), sendo assim, seu app poderá até ser rejeitado durante a tentativa de publicação.

Já passei por isso, e expliquei aos meus superiores o que lhe disse acima e tal "funcionalidade" foi desconsiderada.

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho a não usar métodos internos para fechar o aplicativo, a Apple vai barrar o aplicativo e tem chance do google fazer o mesmo.